# VB.NET Dynamically updating links in VSTO Ribbon

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint

I have a custom Office Ribbon Add-in, built in VB.NET (Framework 4.6.1), on VSTO 2017 (doesn't matter which Office Application, will need to do this in Excel, Word, Outlook, & PowerPoint). The ribbon has a button that takes the user to a link, and that link is currently hard-coded (see example below):

```
Dim myLink1 as String = "http://www.bing.com"
Diagnostics.Process.Start(myLink1)  'Opens to bing.com
```

Is there a way to make this link dynamic? Ideally, I could have a table or resource online somewhere with something like this pseudocode:

```
myLink1 = GoTo("http://MasterURL.com").RetrieveLink(1)
Diagnostics.Process.Start(myLink1) 'I can update myLink1 to google.com
```

That way, I don't need to push out an update to the users in case myLink1 changes, I can just update it on some website MasterURL.com or server somewhere and the ribbon will retrieve it and direct to that page.

This seems like a basic/simple thing, but I cannot seem to find a solution.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would basically need to call a service under your button to get your links from your online storage. (or query database on the end user machine)

To give you an example I google some test API and found this
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/
The sites exposes an API that everyone can call for testing purposes

Here is an example how you can do that (there are many ways) without any error handling etc.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // here is your on-line source
        var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

        string responseFromServer;

        var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm...this makes it a bit more complicated than I had hoped, but the logic makes sense. Thanks for the answer